# Integral inequality of quasi-integrable functions

Tags: measure-theory, almost-everywhere

Let $f,g$ be quasi-integrable functions, wrt. to a sigma-finite measure space $(X, \Omega, \mu)$, with the property that $\displaystyle\int_{A} f d\mu \leq \displaystyle\int_{A} g d\mu$ for all $A \in \Omega$. Here a measurable function $f\colon X \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty, -\infty\}$ is said to be quasi-integrable if at least one of the integrals $\int f^+d\mu$, $\int f^-d\mu$ is finite.

> Does it hold that $f\leq g$ almost everywhere?

Below I have posted an answer to a slightly weaker version of this statement. I am still not sure, whether or not the statement above is true or false.

Comment: Could you please give the definition of quasi-intergability?

Comment: Of course! A function is said to be quasi-integrable, if at least one of the integrals $\int f^+d\mu$, $\int f^-d\mu$ is finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no answer to my question, just a slightly weaker version which I was able to prove:

If $f,g\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ are quasi-integrable with $\int_A fd\mu \leq \int_A g d\mu$ for all $A \in \Omega$, then $f \leq g$ a.e. (so the only difference being that $f$ and $g$ now assume values solely in $\mathbb{R}$).

First we note that it suffices to show $f^+ \leq g^+$ and $f^- \geq g^-$ a.e. Hence without loss of generality we can assume that $f,g \colon X \to [0, \infty)$.
For $h \geq 0$ measurable define $\nu_h$ to be the measure with $\nu_h(A)\equiv \int_A h d\mu$. Our condition on $f$ and $g$ then becomes $\nu_f \leq \nu_g$ and we want to prove that this already implies $f\leq g$ a.e. We now note that both $\nu_f$ and $\nu_g$ are sigma-finite: Indeed let $\{A_n\}_n \subset \Omega$ such that $\bigcup A_n = X$ and $\mu(A_n) < \infty$ for all $n$. Define $A_{nm} \equiv A_n \cap \{f\leq m\}$, then $\bigcup_{n,m\geq 1} A_{nm}= X$ and $\nu_f(A_{nm}) \leq m \mu(A_{nm}) <\infty$. This shows sigma-finitess for $\nu_f$ and analogously for $\nu_g$.
Now let $\{C_n\}_n$ be a sigma-sequence for both $\nu_f$ and $\nu_g$, meaning $\bigcup C_n= X$ and $\nu_f(C_n), \nu_g(C_n)<\infty$ for all $n$. Define $B_m \equiv \{f>g+1/m\}$ and $C_{nm} \equiv C_n \cap B_m$, then we have $\nu_f(C_{nm})=\int_{C_n} f \chi_{B_m}d\mu \geq \int_{C_n}(g+1/m)\chi_{B_m}\geq \nu_f(C_{nm})+\mu(C_{nm})/m$, implying $\mu(C_{nm})=0$ for all $n,m$, and since $B_m \nearrow B \equiv \{f>g\}$ we have by continuity from below $\mu(C_n\cap B)= lim_{m \to \infty} \mu(C_n\cap B_m)=0$ for all $n$, implying $\mu(B)=0$, which is exactly what we wanted.